# Why does command FIND cause my batch script to hang?

Tags: batch-file

I am floored on why the command `find` is causing my batch script to hang.

```
for /f %%a in ('reg query HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ /s') do find /i "tasksche" | echo %%a
```

I can prove this by changing the script up and adding some debug text to show me where the hanging occurs and its this. I have also tried `findstr`, but the same results occur.

I am also open to other suggestions. Sadly, its gotta be a batch, in this environment.

What is needed is a way to search the registry for this pesky wanacry stuff.

Also why on earth is batch scripting the only scripting in the world not having a CONTAINS statement?

Comment: You are not giving the find command any input.

Comment: As long as you're not using an obsolete OS, you should have noticed when checking out the command help, `Reg Query /?`, that there is a built-in search option, `/F`. Using this you may be able to use `Reg Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /S /F TaskSche /D`.

Comment: what's the CONTAINS statement? I've never seen a scripting language with that statement

Comment: Compo is right, the external command __REG__ supports itself finding a registry value on Windows Vista and later Windows versions. __REG__ version 3.0 of Windows XP does not support `/F`. However, if compatibility with Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 is not needed, it is best to use `/F` option of __REG__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of command **FIND** without a file name waits for input from handle **STDIN** to which your code does not send data. So **FIND** is waiting and waiting and waiting for input data.

Most likely you want something like that:

```
for /F "tokens=2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /s 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "tasksche" 2^>nul') do echo %%J
```

Command **FOR** runs in background in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /s 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /I "tasksche" 2>nul
```

**REG** outputs either an error message to handle **STDERR** if queried key does not exist which is redirected to device **NUL** with `2>nul` to suppress it or outputs to handle **STDOUT** all values and subkeys in specified registry key.

This output of **REG** is redirected to handle **STDIN** of command **FIND** with `|` which searches in the lines case-insensitive for `tasksche` and outputs just the lines containing this string.

**FIND** outputs nothing if searched string could not be found in any line which later means the **FOR** command does not execute `echo %%J` at all. An error output by **FIND** to handle **STDERR** is unlikely, but would be redirected also to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with `reg` and `find` with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures output to **STDOUT** of started background command process which are the line(s) output by **FIND**. Then **FOR** splits up each non empty line not starting with a semicolon into substrings using space and horizontal tab as delimiters.

It is specified with **FOR** option `tokens=2*` that second string (registry value type) should be assigned to loop variable `I` and everything after spaces/tabs after second substring should be assigned to next loop variable `J` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) without any further splitting on spaces/tabs.

The registry value type assigned to loop variable `I` is most likely of no interest. Of interest is the full qualified file name output by **REG** and **FIND** as third value which could contain also one or more spaces and being assigned to loop variable **J** of which value is output by **ECHO**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`

Comment: I forgot to answer your second question: The Windows __command__ interpreter is designed for executing commands and applications. That's it. It is __not__ designed for processing text files or processing strings although with `cmd.exe` instead of `command.com` some basic string processing features have been added using `for /F` and `set`. As pure command executions with just basic commands __FOR__, __IF__ and __GOTO__ to control execution order is often not enough, Microsoft added later VBScript, JScript and PowerShell to Windows for enhanced scripting requirements.

Comment: No, You are very informative and I appreciate that.  A lot of the help content (the option /?) is a little vague.